# Реализация JS (AJAX) в C#

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, json

Есть фрагмент кода (json запрос), каким образом можно его реализовать на C#?

https://hastebin.com/junuyaqeco.js [image: скрин кода (на всякий случай)]

Comment: берите постман и генерируйте там код на C# для любого запроса.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091300/posting-json-to-url-via-webclient-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так. Только не забудь поставить нугет `Newtonsoft.Json`

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(endpoint + @""); // твой url
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(@"application/json"));
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(@"api/[твой url]", url);
}
```

Теперь в объекте `response` будет информация об `http` запросе